# Call Java SOURCE using function

Tags: java, windows, oracle, java-stored-procedures

I need to find out the Windows username using SQL, PL/SQL or Java. So far I've found some java code that can return a Windows username. I put the Java code in my schema database, but can't create a function that will call this Java code.

So, my question is:

How can I write an SQL function that will call this Java code below?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED TED."`GetWindowUsername`" as import java.`lang`.*;
import java.`util`.*;
import java.`io`.*;

public class `GetWindowUsername` {
    public static final void main( String `args`[] ) {
        String `userName` = System.get Property("user.name");
        System.out.`println`("Window's Username: "+user Name);
    }
}
```

I found this code on the internet as an example for getting Windows username.

I'm using Oracle Toad as a tool for SQL coding.

Comment: Your database has nothing to do with the windows username of any client user. If you need a windows username in the database, pass it from your client. The database cannot do that.

Comment: Why do you need to create a procedure when you have the java file which gives you the user name. Anyway you can call the java source code using the process like this in oracle. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b12021/invokeapp.htm

Comment: @mallikarjun but then you will get the user name of the sql process. Assuming that the sql server is even running on windows.

Comment: @f1sh ok, but, how can i do that?

Comment: @mallikarjun I will try this, just need to load the class into db. Thank you for advice.

Comment: That code is syntactically invalid as it needs all the back-ticks removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I write an SQL function that will call this JAVA code below?

You need a class containing a static method that will return a value ([another example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49173803/1509264)):

```sql
CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED GetWindowUsername AS
public class GetWindowUsername {
  public static String getUsername()
  {
    return java.lang.System.getProperty("user.name");
  }
}
```

Then you need to create a PL/SQL function to call the Java class's function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION getUsername( in_value IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'GetWindowUsername.getUsername() return java.lang.String';
/
```

Comment: This example works out fine, so far no errors occurred when compiling. Can you write me how to call this function using `sql`? Because when I tried to call the function, I got an error: ORA-00932: inconsistent `datatypes`: expected a Java type at argument position 2 to which some Oracle value can be converted got something else.